# Default getdate() always stores AM for time in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have default value `getdate()` in the blog table in SQL Server database

In fact, I am not even sure if it does store AM or PM in the field

The column `date_created` is of type `datetime` and default value is `(getdate())`

how can I store AM or PM in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)
```

That will yield "Nov 21 2011 1:29PM".  See [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for more formats.

Comment: Which datatype I should be using in table?

Comment: "Jan 1 2005" ? You found a very old example.

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel it'll be `varchar`.

Comment: Well, if i set it to varchar, even getdate() is good enough
THANKS :D

Answer (score 3):

The database is not storing AM or PM... it is storing a specific point in time.  How you represent that point in time visually (through 24-hour time or 12-hour time) is up to how you do your formatting.

Comment: okay okay..Let me absolutely dumb and ask... There is no datatype in MS SQL that can store 7:00:00 AM?

Comment: Based on the comments above, I assume you switched it to a varchar. I would advise against that, as sorting and searching will be a lot slower. Also, the varchar approach is more error-prone and you lose all the bells and whistles that come with times.

To answer your question: datetime CAN store that time... and it is storing that time, it's just not DISPLAYING that as the time.  It might display 19:00:00 instead (24-hour time).

Here is a site showing you different ways of formatting.
http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 2):

> The column date_created is of type datetime

That means it's stored as a binary value that is agnostic about AM/PN and 12/24 hours. All that only happens when you ask for a string representation.

So it could be just the configuration of your App or tools.

Comment: Yeah.. thats why I am so confused... its datetime.. I am just storing it & pulling it by sql & printing it..not doing anything special... but it always prints AM